# django update usage within for loop

Tags: django, sql-update

Within Django, I can't update the database even though all is correct.(I assume :) )

- Should I proceed with query "get" instead of "filter" and use "save"
  instead of "update" ?
  In my database I have P_350 and P_450 columns.
  I am getting no error and also nothing is updated

  ```
  for thing_id, values_dict in groups.items():
          for value_id, value_value in values_dict.items():
              qs = RFP.objects.filter(id__in=thing_id)
              updates = {}
              if value_id == '350':
                  if len(value_value) > 1:
                      updates['P_350'] = value_value
              if value_id == '450':
                  if len(value_value) > 1:
                      updates['P_450'] = value_value
              if updates:
                  qs.update(**updates)
  ```

Here is the prints for the groups.items:

```
397 350 try_3
397 450 try_4
370 350 try_1
370 450 try_2
```

Comment: did you try to `print(updates)`?

Comment: yes I can see when I do that like {'P_350': 'try_3'}

Comment: and what will be if you try to output the `qs.count()`?

Comment: I have done print(qs.count())  and saw 0  0  0  0   Zero's are one below another

Comment: so you just have wrong filter it can be if the `thing_id` is string or not exists in the database.

Comment: Are `P_350` and `P_450` the names of fields in your model?

Comment: Yes P_350 and P_450 are in my model and it's their names exactly ; Bear Brown as you said something wrong with the filtering. Hımm but the thing_id is also in my database there is those id's :)

Comment: Hi, you should try `qs = RFP.objects.filter(id=thing_id)` instead of `qs = RFP.objects.filter(id__in=thing_id)`. the `__in` is looking for list of ids and you are providing a string and it will treat the string as a list instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try `qs = RFP.objects.filter(id=thing_id)` instead of `qs = RFP.objects.filter(id__in=thing_id)`. the `__in` is looking for list of ids and you are providing a string and it will treat the string as a list instead.

Comment: Yes that was the problem.Thank you so much :)